# How to direct to a form page based on category chosen from drop down in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

So I try to create a page for category with dropdown, but I can't direct it to the function for each category that I've chosen and load the form view.
This is the view for choosing the category first

```
    <select name="jenisberkas" id="jenisberkas" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="roya">Roya</option>
    <option value="peralihan">Peralihan</option>
    <option value="validasi">Validasi</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

And this is my controller look like,

```
function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url')
    }

    public function get_jenisberkas()
    {

    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST())
    {

        if($jenisberkas = $this->input->post('jenisberkas')=='roya'; {

        $data['jenisberkas'] = $jenisberkas;
        $this->load->view('roya_v',$data); //directing to the form view for this category
        }
    elseif ($jenisberkas = $this->input->post('jenisberkas')=='peralihan';
    {
        $data['jenisberkas'] = $jenisberkas;
        $this->load->view('peralihan_v',$data); //directing to the form view for this category
    {
```

What I want is when an option is clicked and submitted, it will go directly to specific page form that I made for each options, while passing the value to the page.

I know there's something wrong with my controller and I think I don't need a model since this form doesn't involve a database.

Comment: what you want to achieve??

Comment: @KUMAR what i want to achieve is when an option was selected, after i clicked 'submit' it could go directly to a specific form. is it posible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code fixed:

```
public function get_jenisberkas()
    {

    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) // Removed () from here, added )
    {

        if($this->input->post('jenisberkas') == 'roya') {

        $data['jenisberkas'] = $jenisberkas; // Fix it yourself
        $this->load->view('roya_v',$data);
        }
    elseif ($this->input->post('jenisberkas')=='peralihan')
    {
        $data['jenisberkas'] = $jenisberkas; // Fix it yourself
        $this->load->view('peralihan_v',$data);)
    {
```

I would recommend to use an Intelligent Code Editor like
https://www.eclipse.org/kepler/

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Well, after more than an hour thinking about it, i solved it myself (lmao) with a simple code in my form category view. And after i clicked the submit button, it will go to the specific function made for each category (yay!), that's what i actually want.
so i'm gonna put it here just incase some people out there maybe need solution for this silly case.

this is the view

```
if (isset($_GET["jenisberkas"])) {
      redirect('mulaiberkas/' . $_GET["jenisberkas"] . "");
      exit();
  } 
?>

<form method="get" action="">
    <select name="jenisberkas" id="jenisberkas" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="roya">Roya</option>
    <option value="peralihan">Peralihan</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and the controller is simply contains function named as the value chosen

```
function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

function roya()
    {

        $jenisberkas = $this->input->get('jenisberkas');
        $data['jenisberkas'] = $jenisberkas;
        $this->load->view('roya_v', $data);
        
    }

function peralihan()
    {

        $jenisberkas = $this->input->get('jenisberkas');
        $data['jenisberkas'] = $jenisberkas;
        $this->load->view('peralihan_v', $data);
        
    }
}
```